Plutus Relese 1.21.0.0 is causing AlwaysPass validator to fail
I recently updated my project to plutus tag-1.21.0.0
for a minting contract, the validator is:
{-# INLINEABLE mkValidator #-}
mkValidator :: MintScriptParameter -> MintRedeemer -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkValidator parameter redeemer ctx = case redeemer of
  FirstMint -> True
  FutureMint -> True

{-# INLINEABLE mkWrappedValidator #-}
mkWrappedValidator :: MintScriptParameter -> BuiltinData -> BuiltinData -> ()
mkWrappedValidator parameter redeemer context =
  check $
    mkValidator
      parameter
      (unsafeFromBuiltinData redeemer)
      (unsafeFromBuiltinData context)

mintTokenValidator parameter =
          $$(PlutusTx.compile [||mkWrappedValidator||])
            `applyCode` PlutusTx.liftCode plcVersion110 parameter

i generated the script in the following process:
mintingScript :: MintScriptParameter -> Script PlutusScriptV2
mintingScript param = case mintTokenValidator param of
  Left _ -> error "Error Parsing MintingScript"
  Right compiledCode -> txPlutusScript compiledCode  
  where 
    txPlutusScript :: CompiledCode a -> Script PlutusScriptV2
    txPlutusScript compiledCode = PlutusScript PlutusScriptV2 $ PlutusScriptSerialised (serialiseCompiledCode compiledCode)

but while minting a token i get ScriptError:
{"message":"","type":"PlutusScriptError"}
i tried it with plcVersion100 as well but i got the same result.
